# Login outside Joomla using Curl

Tags: php, curl, joomla, authentication

I tryed to do this on my website and I have this code that works in one of my Joomla instalations but it doesn't work on another joomla instalation. On the instalation that doesn't work, the script does search the database and finds the user credentials but when it goes to mywebsite.com it doesn't log in the user. The users password is not encrypted, it's another field that I use only for this purpose. Can someone help me find out what's wrong?

```
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost", "sqluser", "sqlpass") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("sqldb") or die(mysql_error());
$uname = $_POST['username'];
$upswd = $_POST['password'];
$result_user = mysql_query("SELECT username FROM jos_users where username = '$uname'") or die(mysql_error());
$rows_user = mysql_num_rows($result_user);
$result_pass = mysql_query("SELECT vm_pass_lojat FROM jos_vm_user_info where vm_pass_lojat = '$upswd'") or die(mysql_error());
$rows_pass = mysql_num_rows($result_pass);
if($rows_user > 0){ 
    if($rows_pass > 0){ 
        $url = "http://www.mywebsite.com/online/index.php";
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, TRUE);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, realpath('./cookie.txt'));
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, realpath('./cookie.txt'));
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, TRUE);
        $ret = curl_exec($ch);
        if (!preg_match('/name="([a-zA-z0-9]{32})"/', $ret, $spoof)){
             preg_match("/name='([a-zA-z0-9]{32})'/", $ret, $spoof);
            }
        // POST fields
        $postfields = array();
        $postfields['username'] = urlencode($uname);
        $postfields['passwd'] = urlencode($upswd);
        $postfields['option'] = 'com_user';
        $postfields['task'] = 'login';
        $postfields[$spoof[1]] = '1';
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postfields);
        $ret = curl_exec($ch);
        // Get logged in cookie and pass it to the browser
        preg_match('/^Set-Cookie: (.*?);/m', $ret, $m);
        $cookie = explode('=', $m[1]);
        setcookie($cookie[0], $cookie[1]);
        header("location:  http://www.mywebsite.com/online/index.php");
        }
    else
        {
        echo "WRONG PASSWORD";
    }
    }
else
    {
    echo "NO USER FOUND";
}
?>
```

Comment: Did you forget to indent your code?

Comment: Now it is indented but still does not work, it makes the connections to the database and find the data I want it to find and redirects to the site I want but does not log me in.

Comment: What is in the cookie after the code runs?

Answer (score 0):

The authentication plugin in the backend might not be active.